# Idiom/Phrase for "results without work/effort"

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'd be greatly appreciative of a cleverly devised idiom/phrase that depicts the following concept:

> Results without work/effort.

...and/or...

> My Work/Effort; Your Result.

Any idioms/phrases you can recount or conceive would be of use.

---

## Contextual Edit:

The idiom/phrase should be in the context of service offering/hiring or task delegation, not free-loading as most answers thus far have understandably assumed. E.g.

> [You hire me for] My Work/Effort; [My work/effort produces] Your
>   Result.

Comment: Does your second sentence (My Work/Effort; Your Result.)mean -"You are enjoying the results of my work?"

Comment: I can't think about any idiom that portrays what you want. As far as "My Efforts; Your Results" is concerned, how about using "My sheep, your wool". Disclaimer: I have never seen it being used anywhere.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy It can. It's more in the context of service than free-loading.

Comment: @AshishSingh That's worthy of being added as an answer rather than bashfully obscuring it in the comments.

Comment: @ClarusDignus But since my suggestion isn't a standard usage, I thought it would be better to park my rambling in a safe location i.e. comments.

Comment: Your update appears to contradict the request of 'result without effort'.

Comment: @Josh61 Are you construing payment as effort?

Comment: Sorry, but I think your question is unclear.

Comment: @Josh61 How can I improve it?

Comment: I second @Josh61's comment. It's unclear what you are asking about.

Comment: @Josh61 Let's say you hire me to sell one of your collector Phil Collins LPs. That's an example of my work/effort producing your result. Ultimately, I'm saying appoint someone achieve your objective to spare you the bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your clarifications, how about **"we'll take care of everything"**?

> Even if you think you could do a good job at decorating your home, you might not have a lot of time to do it. In this case, **a professional can take care of everything**. Everything will be done quicker and you’ll be less stressed.

([www.homedit.com](http://www.homedit.com/15-reasons-why-you-should-hire-a-professional-interior-designer/))

Comment: It's not wrong and the answer does correctly intuit what I'm asking. Thanks for being patient enough to fathom a valid response.

Comment: No problem. I'll edit the answer if I come up with more alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

Idioms for

> **Results without work/effort**

(1) ***[Fall Into One's Lap](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fall-or-drop-into-someone's-lap)***:

> (Of something desirable) be acquired by or happen to someone without
>   any effort being made on their part

(2) ***Free Ride***:

> Someone who gets a [free ride](http://www.learn-english-today.com/idioms/idiom-categories/luck/luck-opportunity1.html)- benefits from a collective activity
>   without participating in it.

Comment: That is the most appropriate, I think!

Comment: Please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, ***All [that] you have to do is ask***

Answer (score -1):

An expression commonly used in this context is...

> *He had never had to work or fight for position in society, it was simply [**handed to him on a plate**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22handed%20to%20him%20on%20a%20plate%22) for being born*
>   ...
>    *Lying would be the simplest option given that the excuse had been handed to him on a plate*
>   ...
>   *Alex has just had the easy life handed to him on a plate*
>   ...
>   *The opportunity was handed to him on a plate*
>   ...

---

> [**hand (one) (something) on a plate**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/handed+on+a+plate) (TheFreeDictionary)
>    *To give or relinquish something to one very easily, without them having to work very hard to get or achieve it.*
>   (often used in *passive past tense* constructions)